# Trekking poles on planes

Tags: gear, trekking-poles

Have people been able to bring their (folding) trekking poles onto planes? We're flying without checked-in baggage (on Wizz Air, from Europe to Israel). We've paid for "two large cabin bags", and the poles fit inside them. I'm not asking for promises, obviously, but does anyone have any anecdotal evidence whether this is allowed or not?

Comment: The security staff at Budapest didn't seem to care about the poles ... but who knows what the next flight will bring?

Answer (score 10):

For USA to Canada flights, I have seen hiking poles being accepted (after a bit of explaining..) and refused ([WestJet](http://www.westjet.com/)). If they are refused, you may be asked to go back to the luggage section which may end up making you or your poles miss the flight.

In my experience it seems to vary on the carrier and the person performing the inspection. Because of these variables (and I sometimes use fixed length poles) I generally prefer not having my poles as carry on.

Comment: I can corroborate this inconsistency, I've brought home kids baseball bats (soft, foam) and sometimes they let me bring them onboard, sometimes I have to leave them at security.  I wouldn't risk it, better to pay $25 to have them checked then to have to locate a shop and buy them all over again at your destination.

Answer (score 4):

At UK airports you are not allowed to take them into the cabin. They must be in the hold. You wont get them through security and they confiscate them, whatever airline you are on.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will be entirely random, depending on the airline, the airport and the individual security people who x-ray your bag. I've had climbing gear rejected and put into the hold one one trip, and then next time, accepted - same airport, same airline, just different day :)

Answer (score -2):

This is definitely up to the Pilot, some Pilots may accept it but others won't take you on board, except you pay/get another seat. I'd better check it in if you want to avoid uncomfortable situations

Comment: I think it's the security staff, not the pilot, whose whims decide this issue.

Comment: First instance is the security staff, if they let you past the checkpoint it's up to the Pilot, for example if you take a guitar to the airplane, and you don't want to check your precious as luggage, you need to buy a ticket for that instrument. If anyone questions the passenger (in this example the guitar, but it could be a drunken guy aswell) the pilot has the last word.